# iPad 2 won't charge and turn on

Tags: ipad, charging

My iPad won't turn on and when I try to charge it only the red filler icon (battery icon ) display. The red filler keep blinking three times and then the screen went black. Its keep doing the same thing again again and I even let it charge for more than 2 hours but it won't turn on or charging. This happen suddenly cause usually when the battery died then I charge it, it work. But now it happen like this. Someone please give me advice or what can I do to my iPad ? And what it's problem...

Answer (score 1):

That's classic symptoms of a working iPad, working charge circuitry and a rechargeable Lithium based battery that can no longer take a charge.

Depending on your budget this might be worth paying for a repair or paying for parts and learning about the process to replace a battery. Keep in mind - lithium cells can be fire hazards and if you modify your iPad - it could present a fire hazard if both the old and new battery aren't handled carefully and all safety features aren't correctly reconnected or present in the replacement parts.

Comment: So, all I have to do is send my iPad to apple store and let them fix it? It is working? Or safe?